# How can I call a php file that is on the same folder of a js file without explicitly declaring its url?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file that contains my api called cityguide-api.php and a javascript file called functions.js which are on the same folder (js).

I want to call an api function from my javascript folder, so I wrote:

php:

```
<?php

    function getCities(){
        $cities = get_categories();
        return json_encode($cities);
    }

    if(function_exists($_GET['apifunction'])) {
        $_GET['apifunction']();
    }

?>
```

and on javascript file I am trying to call it like that:

```
jQuery("#city").focus(function(){
        jQuery.getJSON( "cityguide-api.php?apifunction=getCities", function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

But when I try to execute that I am getting a non-found error on the console:

```
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/cityguide-api.php?apifunction=getCities 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I call a php file that is on the same folder of my js file without explicitly declaring the url?

Comment: try with
./cityguide-api.php?apifunction=getCities

Comment: I tried and is the same problem `GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/cityguide-api.php?apifunction=getCities 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: then your file is not in the same dir as  your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the 'current working directory' is not relative to your javascript file, but relative to the html page *your javascript file is loaded in*.

So for example you have two pages: `dir/page1.html` and `otherdir/page2.html`, and you load the same javascript in both files, and from the javascript you call a script, eg. `$.get('script.php');`, then in the firest instance, it'll try to load `dir/script.php` and in the second instance it'll try to load `otherdir/script.php`.

So basically what you want cannot be done. But you can set a base url in your javascript, and use it as a prefix. Example given:

```
var baseURL = '/directory/to/my/app/';
// further down, when you need it
$.getJSON(baseURL + 'api/cityguide-api.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

and what is the path to the executable file (php or html)?
maybe you should place something like

```
'"./../cityguide-api.php?apifunction=getCities"'
```

instead of '"cityguide-api.php?apifunction=getCities"' ?

Comment: no, it is just going one folder upper `http://localhost/wordpress/cityguide-api.php?apifunction=getCities` without the wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

You **can't**. The JavaScript file doesn't know its directory, and when you include it in a html page, the current directory becomes the path of the html file.

You could declare the php path in your html file, since it can find the real path for the php file. Place this in before you close the `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
    var cityguide_api_url = '/your_dir/cityguide-api.php';
</script>
```

After that, your JS file is able to use the `cityguide_api_url` var whenever it wants to call your api.

```
jQuery.getJSON( cityguide_api_url, { 'apifunction': 'getCities' });
```